# Take screenshot of the Displayed OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I made an independent app to show the current user location using OpenStreetMaps. This is my Main Activity:

I used osmdroid 5.6.2

package com.example.re.osm;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location onlyOneLocation;
    private final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1234;
    public GeoPoint startPoint;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);


        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        final IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(18);

        CurrentLocation.requestSingleUpdate(this,
                new CurrentLocation.LocationCallback() {

                    @Override public void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location) {
                        Log.d("Location", "my location is " + location.latitude + " : " + location.longitude);
                        startPoint = new GeoPoint(location.latitude, location.longitude);

                        // My Location Overlay
                        Marker marker=new Marker(map);
                        marker.setPosition(startPoint);
                        marker.setTitle("Your Location");
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                        map.getOverlays().add(marker);
                        map.invalidate();
                        //This geopoint is currently static and shows a single location everytime the app is executed
                        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
                    }
                });



    }
}
```

I need to take the screenshot of the map and display it. Any idea of how should I do it?

Thanks

Comment: copy the code? I don't see the problem

Comment: Yes I did that but the bigger app is too complex and the MainActivity in this code is not the MainActivity in the larger code

Comment: so? Copy it to another activity in the bigger project. It's only like 20 lines of code

Comment: You don't have to run this code in your MainActivity.

Comment: @Tim Dat part is done.. thanks. I edited my question a little to slove another problem.

Comment: @scai then where should I run it?

Comment: @Thomas where to run it is up to you. If you don't know what you're doing, start by doing some beginner's tutorials

Comment: @Thomas In the activity that should display the map.

Comment: @scai Thanks. I did it and its running fine